# IEnumerable to IList casting possibilites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to ensure that my fields and page options are valid and on one page i want to check and see if an item is selected or not - which a selection is required to save.

I have the following:

in ViewEntry: `public IList<Guid> Parties { get; set; }`

in my ViewModel: `public IEnumerable<Guid> PartiesSelected { get; set; }`

Here is my ensure valid code:

```
public void EnsureValid(VisitEntry visitEntry)
    {
        var errors = new RulesException<VisitActivityEntryDTO>();

        if(visitEntry.Parties == null )
            errors.ErrorForModel(string.Format("No {0} selected", Kids.Resources.Entities.Party.EntityNamePlural));
        if (errors.Errors.Any())
            throw errors;
    }
```

and in my controller my Get Edit method when loading the page I have:

```
viewModel.PartiesSelected = visitEntry.VisitEntryParties.Select(v=>v.PartyId);
```

Is it possible in any way that i could possibly have:

```
viewEntry.Parties = viewModel.PartiesSelected
```

or

```
viewEntry.Parties = visitEntry.VisitEntryParties.Select(v=>v.PartyId);
```

I mainly want to have the selected party to show up in the list of Parties for the ViewEntry so when i validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 viewEntry.Parties = viewModel.PartiesSelected.ToList()
```